# convert number to arabic or persian without html tags php

Tags: php, html, arabic

i  want convert number to  arabic without html tags number
my  function is a

```
public function input_html_fa($value_html){


    $value_html1 =  str_replace('<p data-f-id="pbf" style="text-align: center; font-size: 14px; margin-top: 30px; opacity: 0.65; font-family: sans-serif;">Powered by <a href="https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor?pb=1" title="Froala Editor">Froala Editor</a></p>', "",$value_html);



    return  $this->convertNumbers($value_html1,true);;



}


public  function convertNumbers($srting,$toPersian=true)
{
    $en_num = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
    $fa_num = array('۰','۱','۲','۳','۴','۵','۶','۷','۸','۹');


    if( $toPersian ) return str_replace($en_num, $fa_num, $srting);
    else return str_replace($fa_num, $en_num, $srting);
}
```

but html show me this

```
                    <div class="text"><p dir="RTL"><br></p><div align="right"><table border="۲" cellpadding="۱" cellspacing="۱" class="fr-alternate-rows" dir="rtl" style="margin-left: calc(۱۳%); width: ۸۷%;" width="۰"><tbody><tr><td class="fr-highlighted" style="background-color: rgb(۲۰۴, ۲۰۴, ۲۰۴);" valign="top" width="۷.۳۸۳۶۲۷۶۰۸۳۴۶۷۱%"><p dir="RTL"><strong>ردیف</strong></p></td><td class="fr-highlighted" style="background-color: rgb(۲۰۴, ۲۰۴, ۲۰۴);" valign="top" width="۴۰.۱۲۸۴۱۰۹۱۴۹۲۷۷۷%"><p dir="RTL"><strong>تخصص</strong></p></td><td class="fr-highlighted" style="background-color: rgb(۲۰۴, ۲۰۴, ۲۰۴);" valign="top" width="۲۰.۸۶۶۷۷۳۶۷۵۷۶۲۴۴%"><p dir="RTL"><strong>متوسط سابقه کار (سال)</strong></p></td><td class="fr-highlighted" style="background-color: rgb(۲۰۴, ۲۰۴, ۲۰۴);" valign="top" width="۱۶.۸۵۳۹۳۲۵۸۴۲۶۹۶۶۴%"><p dir="RTL"><strong>تمام وقت/پاره وقت</strong></p></td><td class="fr-highlighted" style="background-color: rgb(۲۰۴, ۲۰۴, ۲۰۴);" valign="top" width="۱۴.۷۶۷۲۵۵۲۱۶۶۹۳۴۲%"><p dir="RTL"><strong>مدرک تحصیلی</strong></p></td></tr><tr><td width="۷.۳۸۳۶۲۷۶۰۸۳۴۶۷۱%"><p dir="RTL"><strong>۱</strong></p></td><td width="۴۰.۱۲۸۴۱۰۹۱۴۹۲۷۷۷%"><p dir="RTL">بازاریابی و فروش</p></td><td width="۲۰.۸۶۶۷۷۳۶۷۵۷۶۲۴۴%">۵</td><td width="۱۶.۸۵۳۹۳۲۵۸۴۲۶۹۶۶۴%"><p dir="RTL">۲ نفر تمام وقت</p></td><td width="۱۴.۷۶۷۲۵۵۲۱۶۶۹۳۴۲%"><p dir="RTL">کارشناسی</p></td></tr><tr><td width="۷.۳۸۳۶۲۷۶۰۸۳۴۶۷۱%"><p dir="RTL"><strong>۲</strong></p></td><td width="۴۰.۱۲۸۴۱۰۹۱۴۹۲۷۷۷%"><p dir="RTL">بازاریابی و فروش</p></td><td width="۲۰.۸۶۶۷۷۳۶۷۵۷۶۲۴۴%"><p dir="RTL">۷</p></td><td width="۱۶.۸۵۳۹۳۲۵۸۴۲۶۹۶۶۴%"><p dir="RTL">۲ نفر پاره وقت</p></td><td width="۱۴.۷۶۷۲۵۵۲۱۶۶۹۳۴۲%"><p dir="RTL">کارشناسی</p></td></tr><tr><td width="۷.۳۸۳۶۲۷۶۰۸۳۴۶۷۱%"><p dir="RTL"><strong>۳</strong></p></td><td width="۴۰.۱۲۸۴۱۰۹۱۴۹۲۷۷۷%"><p dir="RTL">مدیریت بازرگانی</p></td><td width="۲۰.۸۶۶۷۷۳۶۷۵۷۶۲۴۴%"><p dir="RTL">۴</p></td><td width="۱۶.۸۵۳۹۳۲۵۸۴۲۶۹۶۶۴%"><p dir="RTL">۱ نفر تمام وقت</p></td><td width="۱۴.۷۶۷۲۵۵۲۱۶۶۹۳۴۲%"><p dir="RTL">کارشناسی ارشد</p></td></tr><tr><td width="۷.۳۸۳۶۲۷۶۰۸۳۴۶۷۱%"><p dir="RTL"><strong>۴</strong></p></td><td width="۴۰.۱۲۸۴۱۰۹۱۴۹۲۷۷۷%"><p dir="RTL">مدیریت استراتژیک</p></td><td width="۲۰.۸۶۶۷۷۳۶۷۵۷۶۲۴۴%"><p dir="RTL">۸</p></td><td width="۱۶.۸۵۳۹۳۲۵۸۴۲۶۹۶۶۴%"><p dir="RTL">۲ نفر پاره وقت</p></td><td width="۱۴.۷۶۷۲۵۵۲۱۶۶۹۳۴۲%"><p dir="RTL">کارشناسی ارشد</p></td></tr><tr><td width="۷.۳۸۳۶۲۷۶۰۸۳۴۶۷۱%"><p dir="RTL"><strong>۵</strong></p></td><td width="۴۰.۱۲۸۴۱۰۹۱۴۹۲۷۷۷%"><p dir="RTL">تیم ترجمه</p><p dir="RTL">(زبان های خاص از جمله فرانسوی، روسی و چینی)</p></td><td width="۲۰.۸۶۶۷۷۳۶۷۵۷۶۲۴۴%"><p dir="RTL">۵</p></td><td width="۱۶.۸۵۳۹۳۲۵۸۴۲۶۹۶۶۴%"><p dir="RTL">۵ نفر پاره وقت</p></td><td width="۱۴.۷۶۷۲۵۵۲۱۶۶۹۳۴۲%"><p dir="RTL">کارشناسی ارشد</p></td></tr></tbody></table></div> </div>
```

but i dont want html tag number change  how can doit?

Comment: There is no actual data to covert within your html. Where is the data coming from?

Comment: What is the string you want to convert and what do you need it to be?

Comment: i want conver only number with data of <p> <tr> i dont want convert number of style's